# Stream screen from Mac to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, streaming

I want to create a program that stream the screen of my Mac to my iPhone. Kind of like it is done in [Liveview](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/liveview/id301069270?mt=8). I'm still relatively new to Objective-C, so I don't know where to start to make such an application.

It seems you have to have something installed both on your Mac and on your iPhone, but how would you actually stream the screen of your Mac to your iPhone?

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

**Update of question**

Thanks for the answers. Still seems a bit vague to me and I'm not sure I really need full video streaming. Implementing also seems to be a pain, since there aren't any real good resources for it.

Taking a screenshot every second or so and streaming it to my iPhone as an image, would actually be ok. I've figured out how to stream an image with Bonjour from my Mac to my iPhone.

The screenshot I need to send to my iPhone is of the design that I'm currently working on in photoshop. I've figured out how to take a screenshot and how to get a list of all open windows. But how to make a snapshot of an open PSD-file, I don't know.

Any suggestions on that?

Comment: What... no one knows in which direction to go?

Comment: Do you realise that you've just changed this question from "how do I stream my screen to an iPhone" to "how can I take a snapshot of an open window"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the frequent screenshot approach. You would prepare a screenshot of the item you want to transmit and then use some easy library like my DTBonjour to transmit these objects via WiFi to iOS clients.

https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/11/and-bonjour-to-you-too/

If you were using layer-backing then you could also use the renderLayer... methods which would also include sub-layers.

The most fidelity you'd get from encoding the individual screen shots in a streaming video format, though this is way more work.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very big subject, so not really something that can be tackled with a simple response. However, I would suggest that one approach would be to write a VNC client for the iPhone. Indeed, this open source exists that's probably worth a look:

http://code.google.com/p/vnsea/

Tim

Comment: Thanks. It's a quite old library though. I've updated the main question. Would love if you have a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is called RFB (or RDP), and most remote-screen applications use RFB/RDP protocol and libraries which implement it.

Comment: I would wager most use VNC but the approach is the same

Comment: VNC uses RFB protocol. And I was wrong, actually I meant RFB, not RDP since RDP is way harder in implementation.

Comment: I've updated my question, so the main problem is a bit different now, but do you have any resources to RFB?

Comment: It is described in Wikipedia at least: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFB_protocol and, there is a number of c open-sourcre implementations.